# find documents with same values in different fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to find all documents in elastic where the values in the fields are the same.

e.g. assume a document with three fields id, parent, child

I want to find where id=parent

Comment: I've since found two other solutions on stack http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064956/elasticsearch-compare-two-fields and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30126620/how-to-find-all-documents-where-the-value-of-one-field-matches-that-of-another?rq=1 why I couldn't find them before posting who knows?

Comment: Though both use a script to achieve the comparison, is there any non script way?